# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.localStorage.getItem') error in react-native

Tags: react-native, local-storage, supabase

I tried to implement supabase with react-native expo app. Then got this error when trying to call a GET API call to get all data from 'Players' table but got an error in localstorage. How to fix this [image: react-native supabase error]

```
const getAllPlayers = async () => {
        try {

            let {data} = await supabase
                .from('players')
                .select('*')

            console.log("all players", JSON.parse(data));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error', error);
        }
    }
```

Can't we access directly supabase just with a react-native app ?

Comment: is the `key` defined?

Comment: I still didn't understand where is that ```key```  from. I didn't do anything about local storage or something. I just do is only added the above code

Comment: According to the Call Stack you have posted, I assume the `key` is related to the `Supabase Auth`. I am not familiar with Supabase. There might have a config file or something related to the Supabase for store `key`s and you might missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently. It was gone after I added options to the `createClient` call of supabase in which I defined the storage for the auth object. Looking like this:

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const options = {
  auth: {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
  },
}

export const supabase = createClient(url, key, options);
```

Btw. I also needed the polyfill for this to work in React Native.

Hope this helps.